# Monitoring Cassandra Server Logs?

Tags: linux, cassandra, fluentd

I've done some searching and have not found any examples of people using something like FluentD to forward Cassandra log file data (system.log) to a log indexer.

Is this something any is doing? If not, why?

If yes, are there example fluentD configs available?

Thanks,
Drew